# Exception: "Недостаточно памяти." при свободной памяти

Tags: c#, память, ram

На компе 12 gb ram + подкачка 3 gb, в момент вылета занято около 5 gb программа берет не больше 1 gb, а конкретно в момент остановки 200 mb, но при выводе изображения `pictureBox2.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(PatchAplicationDataTempOriginal + "\\" + i5 + ".jpg");`
Выходит ошибка

> System.OutOfMemoryException: "Недостаточно памяти."

Comment: 1. Память может быть сильно фрагментирована. Свободной много, но нет непрерывного куска нужного размера. 2. Каков размер картинки (и какой у нее формат: сколько бит на пиксель)? Учитывайте, что размер _файла_ изображения на диске может быть намного меньше, чем размер _объекта_ в оперативке.

Comment: Спасибо, причина была в том что изображение было битым и весило 0, но все же для тех кто с этим встретится в дальнейшем, как лечить выше приведенное

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromfile?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) это правильное поведение при некорректном формате файла (пустой файл также является некорректным).

> OutOfMemoryException
>   Формат файла не является допустимым форматом изображения. - или - GDI+ не поддерживает формат пикселей в файле.

Иначе говоря баг - объявленный фичей. Ни как это не лечится, придется смириться и обрабатывать это исключение.

Как вариант, такой шаблон работы:

```
try
{
    pictureBox2.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(PatchAplicationDataTempOriginal
        + "\\" + i5 + ".jpg");
}
//сюда ссылку на документацию или простое пояснение почему именно такой тип исключения
catch(OutOfMemoryException)
{
    //сообщаем о "битом" файле любым удобным способом
}
```